# How can I prevent my laptop from overheating?

Tags: linux, laptop, cpu, arch-linux, overheating

I have an ASUS X52JB running with ArchLinux (LTS kernel).
The hardware is: Intel Pentium P6100, 4Gb RAM and an ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5145.
The problem is that when I'm using it (especially in summer) the CPU's temperature rises over 70/80°C. I've tried cleaning it up but there was no dust inside the computer. I've also triend installing some software for power usage control but nothing worked. Also tried thermald but it won't start. What can I do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your laptop is not overheating.

Comment: You can try forcibly reducing the maximum speed of the laptop - ie underclocking it.   I have a 1st gen i3 and by underclocking it to minimum clock speed the maximum temperature falls by about 30c.   Of-course, expect lower performance when you do this.  Never used arch, but echo "XXXXXXX" > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpuX/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq for each CPU should do you. (To find out what values of XXXX are available, cat echo "XXXXXXX" > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq )

Answer (score 0):

Multiple others have reported not having CPU Frequency Scaling set-up correctly.  Have you check out this under Arch?

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CPU_frequency_scaling

Comment: I'm trying with _cpupower_ but I didn't understood how to set a maximum frequency, is `cpupower frequency-set -u clock_freq` enough? How can I make this change permanent?

Answer (score 0):

Even though you may not see dust from elsewhere inside the laptop, the fan may have collected a layer of dust over the exhaust fins.  This layer is not easy to get rid of and the best way I've found is to actually take the fan out to clean it.

Answer (score -3):

I have 3 laptops and all three sit on top of Cooling Pads. These are silent and force cooling air unto the bottom of your laptop. My laptops seem to enjoy the cool air and none have suffered any excessive heat. Prices vary greatly but expect to pay around $20.00 for a decent one. Many PC accessories company sell them on-line. You can buy one from any number of big-box stores (Best Buy, Walmart, Target to name a few).
For desk top PC's you can buy extra fans you can place directly on top of the CPU or are built-in on a card that sits in an expansion slot. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: The problem is that with other operating systems such ad Windows I have no overheating problems. I'd like to solve the problem without buying new hardware.

Comment: You need to find out the program which is eating all your CPU under Linux and reign it in.  (Try using TOP).  You may also want to change to a governor like "On-Demand" - if you are using "performance" this could explain some problems.